# Use or in a where clause for zero or is null

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query, i want to display the result if two of my fields are equal at zero or null.

```
foreach ($query=$db->query("SELECT *,
t1.CMD_ID, t1.CMD_CLT_RS, t1.CMD_CLT_ID,
t2.CLT_ID, t2.CLT_CODE
FROM sous_commandes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN commandes AS t1 ON (t1.CMD_ID=sous_commandes.SCMD_CMD_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN client AS t2 ON (t2.CLT_ID=t1.CMD_CLT_ID)
WHERE SCMD_FRN_ID = '$frn_id' AND SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_HT = '0' || IS NULL AND SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_TTC = '0' || IS NULL
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(SCMD_DATE, '%d/%m/%Y') DESC") as $donnees):
```

I tried to use || IS NULL but it doesn't work. No result are display. 
Thanks.

Comment: `||` is [**valid**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html) in MySQL

Comment: Try "AND ( SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_HT = '0' OR SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_HT IS NULL ) AND ( SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_TTC = '0' OR SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_TTC IS NULL )"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_HT = '0' || IS NULL
```

to

```
(SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_HT = '0' OR  SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_HT  IS NULL)
```

same for `SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_TTC`  of course.

**EDIT**

You could also do

```
COALESCE(SCMD_TOTAL_HT, '0') = '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($query=$db->query("SELECT *,
t1.CMD_ID, t1.CMD_CLT_RS, t1.CMD_CLT_ID,
t2.CLT_ID, t2.CLT_CODE
FROM sous_commandes 
LEFT OUTER JOIN commandes AS t1 ON (t1.CMD_ID=sous_commandes.SCMD_CMD_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN client AS t2 ON (t2.CLT_ID=t1.CMD_CLT_ID)
WHERE SCMD_FRN_ID = '$frn_id' AND SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_HT = '0' || isnull(SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_HT) AND SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_TTC = '0' || isnull(SCMD_FACT_TOTAL_TTC)
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(SCMD_DATE, '%d/%m/%Y') DESC") as $donnees):
```